# How to determine whether two SPARQL queries are identical using Python?

Tags: sparql, semantic-web

When using SPARQL to query RDF dataset, the same query can be written in many different ways. For example, sparql queries are always permutation-invariant with respect to some clauses inside it. Also, we can rename the variables inside a sparql query. But how can we identify those identical SPARQL queries? Ideally, there should be a python package that can parse a sparql query (i.e., a string object) into a query object, and different strings share the same underlying query are parsed into the same object, then we can simply compare the parsed query objects to determine whether two sparql queries are identical. Is there any tool like this (seems `prepareQuery()` in `rdflib` doesn't work in this way)? If not, then what should I do?

Semantically identical queries example:

```
SELECT ?x WHERE { ?x foaf:haha ?k .\n ?person foaf:knows ?x .}
SELECT ?s WHERE { ?person foaf:knows ?s .\n ?s foaf:haha ?k .}
```

Comment: *"sparql queries are always permutation-invariant"* —actually, [in SPARQL, order matters](https://blog.blazegraph.com/?p=928). Google something like "python sparql algebra" and then post your answer, please!

Comment: @stanizlav, "... with respect to some clauses inside"! Don't be so nitpicky! :-)

Comment: Identical in terms of what? Semantically? I doubt this is possible for all pairs of queries. Even splitting a BGP of two triple patterns into subqueries and then doing the join would be hard to determine. And that's still a pretty simple case. Doing it just for conjunctive queries (c.f. BGPs in SPARQL) is by the way already research for long time now and part of *query containment* stuff. We also did something in that direction by using subgraph isomorphism. Other did similar stuff. Triple store vendors might have done the same to have better caching, but even here I see limitations.

Comment: @AKSW Yes, by identical I mean semantically identical. I have updated my question with an example. It seems to me that to determine the two queries in my example to be identical is not that hard. Is there any off-the-shelf tool that can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paper [*"Generating SPARQL Query Containment Benchmarks
using the SQCFramework"* by Muhammad Seleem et al.](https://svn.aksw.org/papers/2018/ISWC-Demo-SQCFramework/public.pdf), mentions "SPARQL query containment solvers" where

> Query containment is the problem of deciding if the result set of a query Q1 is included
>   in the result set of another query Q2

If you use such a solver to test whether the result set of Q1 is a subset of Q2 and vice versa, you have established that they are semantically identical.

As for your "off-the-shelf tool": the former paper mentions that those are tested in another paper ["Evaluating and benchmarking sparql query containment solvers." by M.W. Chekol et al..](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-00917911/document)

As for the complexity and computability, the latter paper mentions:

> The query containment problem for full SPARQL is undecidable [15, 1].
>   Hence, it is necessary to reduce SPARQL in order to consider it. A
>   double exponential upper bound has been proven for the containment and
>   equivalence problems of SPARQL queries without OPTIONAL , FILTER and
>   under set semantics [7].

However, query containment in both directions is only one way to determine identity of queries. I am unaware whether there is a proof of a better complexity/computability for query identity than for query containment (or a proof on the contrary).

Comment: Thanks. But I am not quite sure about 'If you use such a solver to test whether the result set of Q1 is a subset of Q2 and vice versa, you have established that they are semantically identical'. I mean queries of different semantics are still possible to have the same results, right? For example, the query to find Tiffany Trump's father and the query to find the president of the US have the same result, but they are obviously of different semantics.

Comment: @YuGu: What I mean is: if A is a subset of B and B is a subset of A, then A and B are identical. The solvers check this on the query level, which means they answer whether this holds for any given model (for any possible knowledge base).

Comment: @YuGu: As followup, what we mean by semantic identity is similar to logical equivalence in logics, see for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence. The definition of equivalence is that the results are equal under all possible circumstances. Under this definition, your example would not be equivalent because there is a possible hypothetical world in which the father of T.T. isn't president.

Comment: Many thanks! By the way, I also found that `prepareQuery()` in `rdflib`, which converts a sparql into a sparql algebra can work for some cases. Do you think it's possible to use sparql algebra object as an approximation for semantic matching when a reasonable loss of accuracy is acceptable?

Comment: @YuGu: Unfortunately, I don't know `prepareQuery()` and SPARQL algebra, so I cannot estimate how well it works, I guess it depends on your own use case.